# How to create a function that allows its functions to use its other function's functions

Tags: javascript, function, dependency-injection

I am familiar with structuring a class and instantiating it into an object in Javascript like the following:

```
var app = (function(){

  function Entity(){
    this.property = "string";
  }
  Entity.prototype.changeProperty = function(param){
    this.property = param;
  }

  var object = new Entity();
  object.changeProperty("number");
  console.log(object);

})();
```

The console log appears as follows:

[image]
.

But I'm have trouble utilizing modular usability of functions in JS. The following is my attempt to grant one function's namespace to another:

```
var appEx = (function(){

  var Model = function(){
    function Entity(){
      this.property = "word";
    } 
    Entity.prototype.changeProperty = function(param){
      this.property = param;
    } 
  };

  var Router = (function(Model){
    var object = new Entity();
    object.changeProperty("number");
    console.log(object)
  })(Model);

})();
```

But this results in my class being unrecognized. What is the most simple way of doing this?

Comment: [Function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope). JS has no classes. Notice also, that you've to return a value from the IIFE, currently `appEx` is `undefined`.

Comment: @teemu What is the correct terminology when describing a function that has this's (properties) and prototype functions (methods) in JS? I'd like to think outside of OO terminology when writing JS but I'm struggling to find the right terms.

Comment: There's no `this` outside of OO. Probably you mean _constructor function_, but that's used to create objects though.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused about the statement "JS has no classes". If you can define a function that allows you to define properties and methods of objects before they are created isn't that called a class?

Comment: In [JS Object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) it is a constructor function, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the object somehow:

```
var appEx = (function(){

  var Model = function(){
    function Entity(){
      this.property = "word";
    } 
    Entity.prototype.changeProperty = function(param){
      this.property = param;
    }
    return Entity;
  }();

  var router = (function(Model){
    var object = new Model();
    object.changeProperty("number");
    console.log(object)
  })(Model);

})();
```

Basically, return `Entity` from `Model`'s iffy and call its object from within `router`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Model.Entity is not a function

Comment: I think it's because you returned Entity. So the model variable is already referencing an Entity. Try to remove the .Entity from new Model.Entity()

Comment: This is correct; change the line so it's "var object = new Model();", since Entity is already returned by Model(). It's not defined using object syntax, so you can't use the dot operator

Comment: @beautifulcoder why do you pass Model as both an input and a parameter? Do you have to rewrite the namespace in order to use the functions of Model?